# Is it possible to view changes of permissions by comparing files to a backup?

Tags: debian, permissions, rsync, backup, version-control

I'm running Debian 9.1 with KDE and used [BackInTime](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/backintime-common) (which uses rsync) to backup my files. Now I would like to create a changelog / diff of changes to permissions of files.

I'd like know this for two reasons: security and [manually restoring permissions if there is no built-in way to do so](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389029/how-to-restore-permissions-with-backintime-rsync). How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
rsync -ani source destination
```

if there will be file permission changes you will see output like

```
rsync -ani 1 new/
.f...p..... 1
```

the flags identify the changed parameter of the file

1. f stands for file
2. p stands for permission changes

Comment: also use the -n flag if you only want to perform a dry run without updates